# What are the android versions suitable for Samsung Galaxy Pocket?

Tags: updates, samsung-galaxy-pocket

Why can't samsung galaxy pocket GT-S5300 be upgraded to android version of jelly bean 4.1.2? It's just being upgraded to 4.1.1 why so?  I've rooted my mobile, but its getting upgraded to ICS 4.1.1 only. I want JB 4.1.2. How can I get it?

Comment: @AlEverett He says he has 4.1.1. That can't be possible, based on the latest firmwares on sammobile. The latest IS 2.3.6, which I mentioned in my answer. So, his question is pretty moot. 4.1.1 is definitely JellyBlast ROM.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure GT-S5300 supports Android 4.1.2? According to [sammobile](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/), the latest version for GT-S5300 is 2.3.6, and it was relased on August 2013.

Maybe you are talking about JellyBlast ROM, which is a custom ROM, and not a stock ROM. Coincidentally, JellyBlast ROM has version 4.1.1.

Comment: Well, SamMobile explicitly states: *All our firmwares are official Samsung firmwares*. So they do not include e.g. CyanogenMod. Seeing it that way, my good old HTC Wildfire would certainly not be running ICS (which it does), or even JB (which it could) :)

Comment: @Izzy What I'm implying is that he may be using JellyBlast ROM 4.1.1, but thinks it's ICS. Unless we see an `About device` screenshot, we won't know for sure.